# how to use random numbers and concatenating a string to the string random_number amount of times in python

Tags: python

How to use random numbers and concatenating a string to another string random_number amount of times in python 3 ????

```
import random
fave_word = 'hello' + 'world'

def randomword(fave_word : str) -> str:
    '''Return something'''
    rand_num = random.randint(0,3)
    for i in range(rand_num):
        fave_word += 'Bob'
print(fave_word)
```

Comment: Not sure what your question is here.

Comment: @M.S The little I can understand from the code is that you are generating a random number, then concatenating it with the string. But the question is still unclear! Kindly rephrase. Thanks.

Comment: Your function is not returning anything and you have not called it.

Comment: One '?' is enough. Try adding explanations / clarifications rather than extra ?'s.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the string you've created. Or you could use [global](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#global), but I'd [not recommend that approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil/19158418#19158418):

```
>>> import random
>>> fave_word = 'hello' + 'world'
>>>
>>> def random_word(word : str) -> str:
...     '''Return something'''
...     rand_num = random.randint(0,3)
...     for i in range(rand_num):
...         word += 'Bob'
...     return word
...
>>> print(random_word(fave_word))
helloworldBobBobBob
>>> print(random_word(fave_word))
helloworld
>>> print(random_word(fave_word))
helloworldBobBob
```